# mysql BLOB problem

Tags: mysql

This works fine.

```
SET @postrownum = 0, @postrank = 1, @postprev_val = NULL, @postprev_postnum = NULL;

SELECT @postrownum := @postrownum + 1 AS row,
@postrank := IF(@postprev_val!=postcount,@postrownum,@postrank) AS postrank,
c.user_id,
@postprev_postnum := IF(@postprev_val!=postcount,@postprev_val-postcount,@postprev_postnum) as morepost,
@postprev_val := postcount as postcount,
postcount*5 as postpoint from

(
select user_id,count(user_id) as postcount from post group by user_id order by postcount desc) as c
```

This doesnt work fine

```
SET @postrownum = 0, @postrank = 1, @postprev_val = NULL, @postprev_postnum = NULL;

select id,postrank,morepost,postcount,postpoint from user as a left join

(SELECT @postrownum := @postrownum + 1 AS row,
@postrank := IF(@postprev_val!=postcount,@postrownum,@postrank) AS postrank,
c.user_id,
@postprev_postnum := IF(@postprev_val!=postcount,@postprev_val-postcount,@postprev_postnum) as morepost,
@postprev_val := postcount as postcount,
postcount*5 as postpoint from

(
select user_id,count(user_id) as postcount from post group by user_id order by postcount desc) as c) as b on a.id=b.user_id
```

morepost will return with [BLOB-1B], weird. Can someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

weird, the problem is with this.

@postprev_postnum = NULL;

i set to

@postprev_postnum = 0;

and it works for 2nd code.

Doesnt understand why thou.